# How do you iterate row index and find the group with the maximum determinant from the dataset in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, combinations

I want to get the 7 index values from my dataset whose group will give me the maximum determinant of |Matrix.T*Matrix| which should be a 6 by 6 matrix.(as my no. of columns is 6).

Dataset:

```
Serial_no,A,B,C,D,E,F
1,0.379,-0.588,-1.69,-0.0135,0.083,-0.0297
2,-0.144,0.278,0.354,-0.000672,-0.0228,0.014
3,0.295,-0.157,-1.63,-0.00451,0.0778,-0.00969
4,0.371,-0.623,-4.98,-0.000253,0.0872,-0.0109
5,0.369,-3.11,-8.3,-0.0000105,0.0871,-0.0327
6,0.369,-0.899,-7.19,-0.0000177,0.0872,-0.0109
7,0.383,-1.04,-2.76,-0.00418,0.089,-0.033
8,0.369,-1.04,-8.3,-0.00000263,0.0871,-0.0109
9,-0.124,0.421,0.679,0.00246,-0.0216,0.0133
10,0.37,2.15,-17.1,0.000244,0.0871,0.0109
11,0.369,5.61,-14.9,0.0000352,0.0872,0.0327
12,0.369,1.45,-11.6,-0.000000963,0.0872,0.0109
13,0.369,3.53,-9.41,-0.00000186,0.0872,0.0327
14,0.369,6.44,-17.2,0.000513,0.0872,0.0327
15,-0.11,-2.57,4.11,-0.000127,-0.0209,-0.0131
16,-0.11,-2.76,4.43,-0.000606,-0.0211,-0.0132
17,0.37,0.761,-6.09,0.0000571,0.0871,0.0109
18,0.3678,1.45,-3.88,0.00209,0.0865,0.0325
19,0.381,-2.46,-19.4,-0.00274,0.0874,-0.0111
20,0.369,4.36,-11.6,-0.000003,0.0872,0.0327
21,-0.111,-1.74,2.79,0.000000903,-0.0209,-0.0131
22,-0.111,-1.91,3.05,-0.000000953,-0.0209,-0.0131
23,0.368,2.28,-6.09,0.000164,0.0871,0.0327
24,-0.11,-0.913,1.46,-0.0000412,-0.0209,-0.0131
25,-0.111,-1.08,1.73,-0.0000101,-0.0209,-0.0131
26,-0.144,-0.278,0.354,0.000672,-0.0228,-0.014
27,0.344,-0.344,-2.76,-0.00202,0.0877,-0.0107
28,0.369,3.11,-8.3,0.0000105,0.0871,0.0327
29,0.383,1.04,-2.76,0.00418,0.089,0.033
30,-0.124,-0.421,0.679,-0.00246,-0.0216,-0.0133
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#importing t dataset with pandas
df=pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')
df = df.set_index('Serial_no')
X=df.iloc[:,:]
```

## I tried this but not getting the row index values of the matrix

```
N = 7
def my_det(df,i):
    mat = df.iloc[i:i+N]
    return np.linalg.det(mat.T @ mat)

all_det = [my_det(df,i) for i in range(len(df)-N)]

print(np.argmax(all_det))
# 7

print(np.max(all_det))
```

dataset:

[image]

Comment: Your code works for me. `np.argmax(all_det)` returns `12`, so the corresponding slice of your original dataframe would be `df[12:12+N]`

Comment: Do you want 7 consecutive rows or can they be scattered? In the first case, brute forcing it should be good enough. In the second case [Cauchy-Binet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) may prove useful.

Comment: @PaulPanzer - They can be scattered in any order. I just want 7 Index values which will give maximum value of |Matrix.T*Matrix| from the complete dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't resist. Here is a solution using Laplace and Cauchy-Binet formulas. And a brute force one for validation.

Sample run:

```
 [55.67740601  0.61391687]
```

This output indicates that on your 30x6 example the brute force and smart solutions gave the same answer and that the brute force took 55.7 seconds while the smart one took 0.6 seconds.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it
import io

def brute_force(A):
    return max(map(list,it.combinations(range(len(A)),7)),
               key=lambda s: np.linalg.det(A[s].T@A[s]))

def smart(A):
    N = len(A)
    # binomial coefficients
    bcs = np.zeros((7,N+1),int)
    # determinants for jxj minors j=1..6
    dets = [A[:,0]]
    bcs[0] = np.arange(N+1)
    # subsets of size j for j=1..7
    combs = [bcs[None,0]]
    for j in range(1,7):
        # extend bcs, combs
        bcs[j] = bcs[j-1].cumsum()
        combs.append(np.zeros((j+1,bcs[j,-j-1]),int))
        combs[-1][0,bcs[j,1:-j-1]] = 1
        combs[-1][0] = combs[-1][0].cumsum()
        for i in range(N-j):
            combs[-1][1:,bcs[j,i]:bcs[j,i+1]] = combs[-2][:,:bcs[j-1,i+1]]
        # use Laplace's formula to compute j+1xj+1 minors
        # the tricky bit is getting the indexing right...
        idxs = np.zeros((j+1,bcs[j,-j-1]),int)
        idxs[1:] = bcs[np.arange(j)[::-1,None],combs[-1][:-1]+1].cumsum(0)
        idxs[-2::-1] += bcs[np.arange(j)[:,None],combs[-1][-1:0:-1]].cumsum(0)
        if j<6:
            dets.append(np.einsum('ji,ji->i',(A[combs[-1]+np.arange(j,-1,-1)[:,None],j])*(-1)**np.arange(j+1)[:,None],dets[-1][idxs]))
        else:
            # use Cauchy-Binet to calculate the M^T M determinants
            d62 = np.square(dets[-1])
            d7 = d62[idxs].sum(0)
            # find index of max, translate back to subset
            return combs[-1][::-1,d7.argmax()]+np.arange(7)

a = """
Serial_no,A,B,C,D,E,F
1,0.379,-0.588,-1.69,-0.0135,0.083,-0.0297
2,-0.144,0.278,0.354,-0.000672,-0.0228,0.014
3,0.295,-0.157,-1.63,-0.00451,0.0778,-0.00969
4,0.371,-0.623,-4.98,-0.000253,0.0872,-0.0109
5,0.369,-3.11,-8.3,-0.0000105,0.0871,-0.0327
6,0.369,-0.899,-7.19,-0.0000177,0.0872,-0.0109
7,0.383,-1.04,-2.76,-0.00418,0.089,-0.033
8,0.369,-1.04,-8.3,-0.00000263,0.0871,-0.0109
9,-0.124,0.421,0.679,0.00246,-0.0216,0.0133
10,0.37,2.15,-17.1,0.000244,0.0871,0.0109
11,0.369,5.61,-14.9,0.0000352,0.0872,0.0327
12,0.369,1.45,-11.6,-0.000000963,0.0872,0.0109
13,0.369,3.53,-9.41,-0.00000186,0.0872,0.0327
14,0.369,6.44,-17.2,0.000513,0.0872,0.0327
15,-0.11,-2.57,4.11,-0.000127,-0.0209,-0.0131
16,-0.11,-2.76,4.43,-0.000606,-0.0211,-0.0132
17,0.37,0.761,-6.09,0.0000571,0.0871,0.0109
18,0.3678,1.45,-3.88,0.00209,0.0865,0.0325
19,0.381,-2.46,-19.4,-0.00274,0.0874,-0.0111
20,0.369,4.36,-11.6,-0.000003,0.0872,0.0327
21,-0.111,-1.74,2.79,0.000000903,-0.0209,-0.0131
22,-0.111,-1.91,3.05,-0.000000953,-0.0209,-0.0131
23,0.368,2.28,-6.09,0.000164,0.0871,0.0327
24,-0.11,-0.913,1.46,-0.0000412,-0.0209,-0.0131
25,-0.111,-1.08,1.73,-0.0000101,-0.0209,-0.0131
26,-0.144,-0.278,0.354,0.000672,-0.0228,-0.014
27,0.344,-0.344,-2.76,-0.00202,0.0877,-0.0107
28,0.369,3.11,-8.3,0.0000105,0.0871,0.0327
29,0.383,1.04,-2.76,0.00418,0.089,0.033
30,-0.124,-0.421,0.679,-0.00246,-0.0216,-0.0133
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(a),index_col=0)

from time import perf_counter as pc
T = []
T.append(pc())
xb = brute_force(df.to_numpy())
T.append(pc())
xs = smart(df.to_numpy())
T.append(pc())

assert (xs==xb).all()
print(np.diff(T))
```

Comment: Here for ```xb``` & ```xs```  I am getting output as ```[ 0  1  2  4 13 18 28]```. But I do not have an index ```0```. So are these positions of my actual indexes?

Comment: Currently I am getting only the Index Positions. How to fetch the actual value at that positions?

Comment: `df.index[xs]`?

Comment: Instead of maually specifying 7, If I take  ```U = int(input('User Input'))```, thats greater than ```len(df.columns)```, its working for ```brute_force``` but for ```smart``` it is giving error of ```ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (8,)``` . Suppose if you take  ```U = 8``` in this case.